# Output all steps of Sort

Tags: sorting

Is there a way you output each partial result of the `Sort` function? i.e.

```
Sort[{2,3,1}]
{2,1,3}
{1,2,3}
```

Comment: @Andrew Good point. I'm not concerned with a particular algorithm, I just want to apply a function to each of the partial results that differ by one transposition to the previous one. If it can't be done with Sort then I guess the only option is to implement a sorting algorithm, right?

Comment: [Bubble Sort -  all steps](https://youtu.be/lyZQPjUT5B4)

Comment: related?: [How can I highlight a moving bar in an animation of a bar chart?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17550/125)

Comment: Since OP is "not concerned with a particular algorithm" this looks like a duplicate of [(18430)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18430/121), and I am marking it as such, pending further clarification or differentiation of the question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I guess you are technically right, but I'm not asking for any visualisation. Just output the list of lists so none of the answers is a direct match to my question.

Comment: I realize your question is not exactly the same but (as the banner reads) it "already has an answer" as given by the line `seqs = FoldList[#1 /. #2 &, s, t0]` in belisarius's answer.  The term *duplicate* (yes, I used it) is not really representative of the close reason; the banner gives a more accurate meaning and purpose.  To put it another way your question is a strict subset of that one, unless you have additional specific requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

[image]

If the task is purely instructive, we can take a look at an inefficient but very concise and illuminating implementation of [Bubble Sort Algorithm with Patterns and Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/ImplementTheBubbleSortAlgorithmWithPatternsAndRules.html). The whole thing to sort the data:

```
data = RandomInteger[99, 10]
```

> {53, 93, 31, 20, 70, 89, 81, 53, 62, 41}

is a oneliner:

```
data //. {a___, b_, c_, d___} /; b > c -> {a, c, b, d}
```

> {20, 31, 41, 53, 53, 62, 70, 81, 89, 93}

We can use that to extract every step and build a visualization. Start with defining a single-step function:

```
sortstep := # /. {a___, b_, c_, d___} /; b > c -> {a, c, b, d} &
```

Where the difference with original is in replacing, pun intended: `//.` aka `ReplaceRepeated` with `/.` aka `ReplaceAll` (you could also use more safe `Replace` in general). Sort tracking every step:

```
sorted = Most[NestWhileList[sortstep, data, UnsameQ[##] &, 2]];
```

Build a visualization of the process that you can see at the top of the post:

### Vis 1

```
st1 = Directive[Black, Thick, Opacity[.2]];
st2 = Directive[Red, Thickness[.01], Dashed];

Manipulate[
    ListLinePlot[sorted[[;;k]],
        Filling->Bottom,
        PlotStyle->Table[st1,k-1]~Join~{st2},
        FillingStyle->Directive[Gray,Opacity[.05]],
        PlotTheme->"Business",
        ImageSize->500],
{k,2,Length[sorted],1}]
```

### Vis 2

```
Manipulate[
    BarChart[sorted[[k]],
        PlotTheme->"Detailed",
        ImageSize->500],
{k,2,Length[sorted],1}]
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with visualisation but I'm accepting this answer as the output I want is in sorted variable.

Answer (score 3):

For fun  and starters: Modifying [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17606/125) slightly:

```
bsort2[list_] := Module[{A = Style[#, GrayLevel[.6]] & /@ list, tmp}, 
   tmp = Reap[Do[If[First /@ (A[[j]] > A[[j + 1]]), 
        Sow[A /. (A[[j]] -> (A[[j]] /. GrayLevel[.6] -> Red))];
        {A[[j + 1]], A[[j]]} = {A[[j]], A[[j + 1]]}], {i, 
        Length@A}, {j, Length@A - i}]][[2, 1]]; Append[tmp, A]];
```

Examples:

```
bsort2@RandomSample[Range[5]]
```

> [image]

```
opts = {ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[White], 
   BaseStyle -> (FontSize -> 14), AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> False, 
   Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 2};

ListAnimate[Column[{#, BarChart[Labeled[#, #, Above] & /@ #, opts]}, 
    Alignment -> Center] & /@ bsort2@{2, 3, 1}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]