# Straightforward way to highlight a single bar in a BarChart

Tags: plotting, charts

I'm looking for a straight forward way to highlight a single bar in a `BarChart`, i.e. a BarChart of country GDP where you highlight your country.

There's a [great animation QA with a highlighted bar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17550/how-can-i-highlight-a-moving-bar-in-an-animation-of-a-bar-chart) but I couldn't figure out how to simplify that down to a simple static barchart.

I think it should be via a `ColorFunction` rule with a user defined function but I'm not getting it, i.e.

```
data = Range[6]*2;
f[x_] := If[x == 1, Hue[0.5], Hue[0.2]]
BarChart[data,
 ColorFunction -> f,
 ChartLabels -> Characters["abcdef"]]
```

does something similar to what I want but I can't figure out how to change which bar gets highlighted (or why it's that one - for any other number but `1` I lose the highlighted bar).

I would have thought I could specify the `ChartLabel` for the data point but I haven't figured out that either.

Comment: almost - mostly a typo and need to have ColorFunctionScaling False:
data = Range[6]*2;
f[x_] := If[x == 6, Hue[0.5], Hue[0.2]]
BarChart[data, ColorFunction -> f,  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ChartLabels -> Characters["abcdef"]]

Answer (score 9):

There are several wrappers that you can use to wrap around data. Please read the Details and Options section of the docs. If I understand you correctly you want to choose to highlight one bar only. A colour function will do that but easier simply to use a wrapper for highlighting one bar.

One way would be to replace the datum that you want highlighted with a wrapper version:

```
BarChart[data /. 4 -> Style[4, Red]]
BarChart[data /. 4 -> Callout[4, "Hello World"]]
```

[image]

Alternatively modify the data directly, e.g:

```
data[[2]] = Style[data[[2]], Red];
data[[3]] = Callout[data[[3]], "hello world"];
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen the wrapper of changing the style of the data point and then having it become part of the chart.  BTW your Callout function doesn't work for me (v11.0.1).

Comment: `Callout` is >= 11.1

Answer (score 4):

This approach allows you pick the bar that is highlighted by its label.

```
Module[{n = 6, chr = "d", data, lbls, assoc},
  data = 2 Range[n];
  lbls = CharacterRange["a", FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode["a"] + n - 1]];
  assoc = AssociationThread[lbls, data];
  BarChart[data /. assoc[chr] -> Style[assoc[chr], Hue[.5]],
    ChartStyle -> Hue[.2], ChartLabels -> lbls]]
```

[image: chart]

Answer (score 3):

As a *not-so-straightforward-yet-fun* alternative, you can use a custom `ChartElementFunction`. In the following example, bars to be highlighted are indicated by  metadata.

```
ClearAll[highlightBar]
highlightBar[d_: 1, r_: 3] := Module[{t}, 
    If[#3 === {}, System`BarFunctionDump`BasicBar[##], 
     Dynamic[t = Clock[{0, 1, 0.05}, d, r]; 
      Dynamic[{EdgeForm[], CurrentValue["Color"], 
       If[#3 === {"up"}, Rectangle[Transpose[#][[1]], {1, t} Transpose[#][[2]]], 
    Rectangle[Dot[{1 - t, t}, {Mean /@ #, Transpose[#][[1]]}], 
     Dot[{1 - t, t}, {Mean /@ #, Transpose[#][[2]]}]]], 
   FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle @@ Transpose@#}]]]] &;
```

Examples:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, Style[3, Red] -> "up", 4, Style[5, Green] -> foo}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> highlightBar[2, 10]]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3 -> blah, 4, 5 -> blah}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> growingBar[1, 10], ChartStyle -> 64]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
data = Range[6]*2;
f[x_] := ReplacePart[ConstantArray[Hue[0.2], Length@data], x -> Hue[0.5]]
BarChart[data, ChartStyle -> f[3], ChartLabels -> Characters["abcdef"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And finally via use of a ColorFunction.  It was hard to figure out because  ColorFunctionScaling defaults to True and doesn't work unless you use the full expression form of Function.

```
BarChart[data, ColorFunction -> Function[{x}, If[x == 3, Red, Gray]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be the ugliest way to do it but it is certainly straightforward - I'm just adding it here for completeness.

```
data = Range[6]*2;
p1 = BarChart[data, ColorFunction -> f, 
   ChartLabels -> Characters["abcdef"]];
data2 = {0, 0, data[[3]], 0, 0, 0};
p2 = BarChart[data2, ChartStyle -> Red];
Show[p1, p2]
```