# Change colour of bar in stacked bar chart within range

Tags: charts

I'm trying to change the colour of a bar when a number falls within the range. 
For instance, here is a stacked bar chart

```
BarChart[{40, 20, 20, 20}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 BarOrigin -> Left]
```

[image]

If I have the number 70, I would like to change the colour of the third bar, leaving the other ones the same.

I have tried using ReplaceAll to create a wrapper version as per the first answer of this question. 
[Straightforward way to highlight a single bar in a BarChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162523/straightforward-way-to-highlight-a-single-bar-in-a-barchart)
Yet, since it doesn't take the sum of my data points, it did not work. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
list = {40, 20, 20, 20};
BarChart[
 MapAt[
  Style[#, Red] &,
  list,
  FirstPosition[
   Accumulate@list,
   _?(GreaterThan@70)
   ]
  ],
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 BarOrigin -> Left
 ]
```

[image]

Essentially, this works by using [`Accumulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html) to compute the net bar sizes in the stacked chart. Using [`FirstPosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FirstPosition.html), we find the position where the element crossing `70` is. And finally, [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) allows us to modify the element at the determined position.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is to use a custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
BarChart[list, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left,    
  ChartElementFunction -> ({If[#[[1, 1]] <= 70 <= #[[1, 2]], Red], 
    ChartElementData["Rectangle"][##]} &)]
```

[image]

Or define a function that works for all 4 settings for the option `BarOrigin`:

```
ClearAll[ceF]
ceF[t_, color_: Red, cedf_: "Rectangle"] := Module[{tr, part, 
     bo = Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BarOrigin"]},
   tr = Switch[bo, Top | Right, -t, _, t];
   part = Switch[bo, Top | Bottom | Automatic, 2, _, 1];
   {If[#[[part, 1]] <= tr <= #[[part, 2]], Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"] = color],
    ChartElementDataFunction[cedf][##]}] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
list = {40, 20, 20, 20};

Row[Framed @ BarChart[list, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ImageSize -> 250, 
     BarOrigin -> #, ChartElementFunction -> ceF[70], PlotLabel -> #] & /@
  {Bottom, Top, Left, Right}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
Row[Framed @ BarChart[list, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ImageSize -> 250, 
    BarOrigin -> #, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
    ChartElementFunction -> ceF[70, Yellow, "GlassRectangle"], PlotLabel -> #] & /@ 
 {Bottom, Top, Left, Right}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]